# class not registered error returned from CoGetClassObject

Tags: windows, com

I created a COM dll using vs2008 ATL wizard. I created a new interface and implemented two methods. The default functionality is handled by the wizard I want to access this COM component from another application.

When I use CoCreateInstance() or CoGetClasObject() , I'm getting class not registered error (0x80040154). Did I miss something to implement in the COM dll? I registered the dll using regsvr32 and corresponding entries for CLSID, IID, Typelib were created in registry.

```
Client Code:

::CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

ISampleCOM* pSampleCOM;

HRESULT hr = ::CoGetClassObject(CLSID_CSampleCOM,CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,NULL,
                    IID_ISampleCOM, (void**)&pSampleCOM);
```

hr is returning (0x80040154) class not registered error

Any help would be greatly helpful for me

Comment: Have you tried CLSCTX_ALL instead of CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER ?

Comment: There are *hundreds* of questions about this error code already.  At least review the existing answers, then come back and explain why *none* of them applied to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you are accessing the com object from , for eg 32 bit application will access the object whose assembly is build with x86 configuration and 64 bit application will access the object whose assembly is build with x64 configuration.

Comment: A 32 bit application uses the com object build with x86 configuration

Comment: I'm using 64bit OS and used regsvr32 from cmd to register the dll. I did not explicitly use c:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32 to register. Is this creating the problem

Comment: might be. You can check the registry entry where your object info ( progid and clsid ) is present, which will give clear information